# Unsupported grant type with API

Tags: java, android, json, api, token

I'm trying to get token from sever response it works great with postMan , but when debug it with android it gets error:

> unsupported_grant_type

here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(LoginURL);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// post.setHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("grant_type", "password");
    obj.put("password", PasswordEditText);
    obj.put("username", EmailEditText+"gfg");

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    results = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    myObject = new JSONObject(results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have found the solution :

replace :

```
  post.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

With:

```
                post.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=password&username=0000@gmail.com&password=00000", "UTF-8"));
```